# Import CSV to MS Access without setting table column

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have managed to import a csv file into a ms access table before, but this was done by specifying the table columns beforehand to match the csv. I am planning to tackle a larger csv file and was wondering if it is possible to have the table columns entered programmatically.

```
Private Sub Import_Click()
'import excel file

'delete current table data
 With CurrentDb
 CurrentDb.Execute "DeleteTableData"
End With

'import
Dim f As Variant
Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
'set dialog title
With f
.Title = "Choose File"
f.AllowMultiSelect = False

'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the 
user's action.
'The user pressed the action button.
If .Show = -1 Then
For Each f In .SelectedItems


'import into table
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "[Table1]", f, True
Next f
MsgBox "File Imported"
Else
'Show if Canceled is selected in a message box
f = "No File Selected to Import."
MsgBox f
End If

End With
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

The user is able to choose any csv file they want and onclick it will import it and enter the data into a table.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I already managed to solve it. Turns out I only had to change the HasFieldName parameter to false. Thanks for the help though :) Sorry, I'm a bit new here, so do I need to answer my question now or do I do anything else?